# Broadcom 802.11n won't connect to home network

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11n, broadcom

This has been very frustrating.  I have updated firmware on my old router. I updated bios. Uninstalled wireless card and rebooted. Updated wireless driver. Bought a new router.  I get ip address and default gateway. It says connected but limited. I can't ping anything other than NIC.  Dell came and replaced motherboard, wireless antenna, and card.  I can connect to wireless at work just fine. I have no idea whats going on other than this card is a big PoS.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

n uses the 5ghz range and a/b/g use the 2.4ghz range. its possible that your router only has the a/b/g - 2.4ghz antenna active and your card is set to N network only or vise versa... i would check settings on both.